# Changing bipartite network data in incidence matrix format by using 'for' loops

Tags: r, for-loop, social-networking, adjacency-matrix, bipartite

[Data_link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5mLoZkcC8VxWGJ5aU8wcmV1VFk)

Hi, 
The link above is the data that I'm working with and I'm trying to change my data format to incidence matrix by using loops of 'for' functions.

If you see the data that I have('Edgelist sheet'), titleIDs are in the first column and the nodes(people participated in that movie) are in the third column.

The data format that I'm trying to transform to is a incidence matrix which titleIDs are in row and people's names are in column and 1 if the people participated in the movie and 0 if the people didn't. By using this, I'm trying to conduct a bipartite network analysis(two-mode network analysis) later.

Below is the code that I worked on, but as you see, there are too many loops that it takes too long for r to handle and I'm not sure whether this is the correct code.

Is there any way to make the code more efficient??

```
library('xlsx')
setwd("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\analysis")
movie <- read.xlsx2("Data.xlsx", sheetIndex=3)
edgelist<-read.xlsx2("Data.xlsx", sheetIndex=2)
namelist=edgelist[,3]
names <- unique(namelist)
titleID<- movie[,1]

mat_dat= matrix(0,ncol=length(titleID),nrow=length(names))
dimnames(mat_dat) = list(names,titleID)
mat_dat

pp<-edgelist[,3]
tt<-edgelist[,1]

dim(mat_dat)

for(i in 1:17892){                  #total number of edges
    for(k in 1:2625){               #total movie titles(non-redundant)
      for(l in 1:9021){             #total numbers of people(non-redundant)
        if(titleID[k]==tt[i] & names[l]==pp[i]){
          mat_dat[l,k]<-1 
        }
        else mat_dat[l,k]<- mat_dat[l,k]
      }
    }    
  }
```